# How to use JSON array with template literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

I am learning javascript and using Fetch to retrieve and parse some JSON from a URL. The console logs the JSON array, but when I attempt to use it in a template literal I get an error in the console `"positions is not defined"`. That is where I am getting hung up as most of the examples and tutorials do not show the JSON formatted the way I am getting it.

How would I access this so I could use it in a template literal how I want to or is there a better way? I do not want to loop through it as I want to be able to place certain values where I need or want them.

Example of code I am working with:

```
let positionData = new Request('URL_TO_JSON')

  fetch(positionData)
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json){

        document.getElementById('online').innerHTML = `THERE ARE CURRENTLY ${positions.lenght} CHASERS LIVE`;

        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = `${positions[0].name}`;

        console.log(json)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}` )
      });
```

In the console, it displays the JSON array as follows:

```
{positions: Array(2)}
positions: Array(2)
0: {report_at: "2019-04-26 20:29:29", lat: "33.0851707", lon: "-96.8177032", elev: "0", dir: "0", …}
1: {report_at: "2019-04-26 05:07:29", lat: "33.0173721", lon: "-96.5511093", elev: "0", dir: "0", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

According to the tutorials and videos I have been watching it shows all I need to do is this and I think this is where my problem is because of how the JSON is prefixed with `Positions`.

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = `${positions[0].name}`;
```

But I get "positions is not defined" error in the console.

Comment: Try with json.positions[0].name

Comment: Probably `${json.positions[0].name}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in `json` which contains `positions`, so you should say:

```
document.getElementById('online').innerHTML = `THERE ARE CURRENTLY ${json.positions.length} CHASERS LIVE`;`

document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = `${json.positions[0].name}`;
```

Notice that `lenght` should be spelled `length` too :-)

Comment: Could you explain for my future reference why I needed to prefix it with `json`? Is it because of the `.then(function(json){`? If what was something else like `foo` I would have used that? Also is it because that JSON contained a key? If it didn't have that key would it have just simply been `${json.length}` for example?

Comment: Exactly.  The variable `json` in `.then(function(json){...`  could have been called anything you wanted.  In a Promise (like Request) the `.then` method should be sent a callback function which will receive the data if and when it becomes available.  It so happens that Request passes some JSON data when the Promise resolves.  Your function is receiving it in a variable called `json`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `positions` is a key in the object named `json` that you are returning.

Try using

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = `${json.positions[0].name}`;
```